# Get duplicate line and the rest of the file [ Big file 50G]

Tags: python, sed

i have a big file **50G** and i want to get the **duplicate line** and **rest of file** i use two command to get the result and that Take a long time.

```
sort file.tsv | uniq -d > duplicateList.tsv 
sort file.tsv | uniq -u > clean_List.tsv
```

As you can see the process repeated twice , i want to make only one commande and return the both result without using duplicate commande

note i can use linux commande or Python script

Comment: Did you try using `tee` with which you can pipe your file contents to different consumers/files?

Comment: Yes, I tried tee ,But did not solve my problem

Comment: Please define *"a long time"*. Please show exactly how you used `tee` and how/why that *"didn't work"*. Please show a few representative lines of your TSV file. Thank you.

Comment: i mean "a long time" The process is run twice for example if the first command take 15min i need to run the next command and its take 15min ,I want to save  duplicate email in file named duplicateList.tsv and save no duplicate email in folder named clean_List.tsv  in the same action
,,my TSV file format is a email liste aa@email.com

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed), presumes the file is already sorted:

```
sed -Ee 'N;/^(.*)\n\1$/!{P;D};:a;$w duplicatesFile' \
     -e '$d;N;/(\n.*)\1$/ba;h;s/.*\n/\n/;x;s/(.*)\n.*/\1/w duplicatesFile' \
     -e 'x;D' file > nonduplicatesFile
```

In overview: the duplicates are written out to the `duplicatesFile` and the remainder to `stdout` which is redirected to `nonduplicatesFile`.

Initially a 2 line buffer is created and patterned matched for duplicate lines. If not, the first line is printed to stdout and then deleted and repeated until a duplicate line occurs.

For duplicate lines the edge case of end-of-file is handled first, where all the remaining lines are output to the `duplicatesFile` and processing is halted.

For the other case, the pattern space is copied to the hold space and then split into duplicates and non-duplicate. The duplicates written to then `duplicatesFile` and the non-duplicate, prepended with a newline and then the newline deleted using the `D` command which causes the sed commands to be rerun less the implicit fetching of the next line from `file`.

N.B. Sed is never the fastest solution perhaps in this case a dedicated piece of code might provide the required speed.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is by far the fastest.  Here's how in python:

```
name = '/my/big/file'
lines = dict()
dups  = dict()
with open( name ) as f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    for line in f:
        if line in lines:
            dups[ line ] = True
        else:
            lines[ line ] = True
print( 'Duplicate(s)' )
for line in dups:
    print( line )
print( 'Unique(s)' )
for line in lines:
    if line not in dups:
        print( line )
```

Python dictionaries are implemented as a hashed collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this syntax:

```sh
sort file.tsv > >(uniq -d > duplicateList.tsv) > >(uniq -u > clean_List.tsv)
```

It will send the stdout to both commands, so sorting only happens once, and the other two in parallel.